# git lfs upload says file is too large

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I've installed github LFS after initially recieving the following error:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: error: Trace: 3fb0a62c4539fc003fc93be5631aaa79cfc7400a9c050d859388f1789dbd9d61
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File public/videos/SHOWREEL.mp4 is 212.07 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/LINKTOREPO
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/LINKTOREPO'
```

I've tried running the following commands in order:

```
> git lfs install
Updated Git hooks.
Git LFS initialized.

> git lfs track "*.mp4"
Tracking "*.mp4"

> git lfs push --all origin main
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (4/4), 222 MB | 0 B/s, done.

> git add .

> git push -u origin main
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (4/4), 222 MB | 0 B/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 46, done.
Counting objects: 100% (46/46), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Writing objects: 100% (46/46), 211.59 MiB | 13.74 MiB/s, done.
Total 46 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
```

and then it continues to give the error I've specified before.

Why is it erroring out? I'm using LFS, would I have to commit everything without the MP4 first and then commit the MP4 separately?

Comment: You are already tracking the file without lfs, you need to modify your history to remove the big file before you can push to github.

Comment: The answer to your question about how to fix it seems to litterally be on the frontpage of git-lfs.com

Comment: Use `git lfs migrate import --include-ref=main --include="*.mp4"` to convert all mp4 files in the history of `main` into LFS managed data. Note that it rewrites the history, so you need `git push -u -f origin main` to overwrite `main` in the remote repository.